# React connection to Django

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, webpack

There is a built React project with the following file structure:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Mz1.png) or:

```
dist
| assets
| | css
| | | appPage.blablabla.css
| | img
| | | mainPanel
| | | palettePanel
| | | structuralPanel
| | | workingSpace
| js
| | appPage.blablabla.js
| app.html
```

app.html - main html file
js - folder with js file
assets - foler with folders with some static files

How can I include it to my django app?

Comment: What does the documentation say to do?

Comment: I don't think you can use react to build the backend application inside the frontend, the backend with django is separated on most of applications so when you deploy your app, you deploy your backend in one server and your frontend on another, but if you have to put the backend and the frontend on the same server you have to put your frontend inside of your backend, something like this: https://mrvaibh.medium.com/react-django-full-stack-the-best-web-integration-e9d92af43b96

Comment: I think that best approuch is just to make django for backend not for rendering websites or sth. So i would make like django api backend to gain data or sth.

Answer (score 0):

You must manually configure the react app with webpack if you wish to have the react app in your Django folder. Or you can host it as a static website by running `npm run build` in react project and put build folder to static folder in your Django folder. Or you can separate both. As server and client.